# redirect to index.php if i type domain name

Tags: php, mysql, .htaccess, zend-framework, mod-rewrite

I am developing a project in zend framework 1.12
To redirect domain on index.php I used two .htaccess, one in root and one in public folder

My problem is that when I type domain name it should redirect on index controller.

Folder structure is as below

```
application
--configs
----application.ini
library
--Zend
public
--css
--js
--index.php
--.htaccess

.htaccess
```

Below is written in root .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule (.*) public/$1
```

Below is written in public/.htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
# The following rule tells Apache that if the requested filename
# exists, simply serve it.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
# The following rewrites all other queries to index.php. The 
# condition ensures that if you are using Apache aliases to do
# mass virtual hosting, the base path will be prepended to 
# allow proper resolution of the index.php file; it will work
# in non-aliased environments as well, providing a safe, one-size 
# fits all solution.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)(.+)::$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [E=BASE:%1]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %{ENV:BASE}index.php [NC,L]
```

application/configs/application.ini

```
[production]
phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 1
phpSettings.display_errors = 1
includePaths.library = APPLICATION_PATH "/../library"
bootstrap.path = APPLICATION_PATH "/Bootstrap.php"
bootstrap.class = "Bootstrap"
appnamespace = "Application"
resources.frontController.controllerDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "/controllers"
resources.frontController.params.displayExceptions = 1

resources.frontController.moduleDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "/modules"

resources.layout.layoutPath = APPLICATION_PATH "/layouts/scripts/"
resources.frontController.baseUrl = "/"

resources.session.remember_me_seconds = 864000

[staging : production]

[testing : production]
phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 1
phpSettings.display_errors = 1
resources.db.adapter = "PDO_MYSQL"
resources.db.params.host = "localhost"
resources.db.params.username = "root"
resources.db.params.password = "root123"
resources.db.params.dbname = "labs"
resources.db.isDefaultTableAdapter = true

[development : production]
phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 1
phpSettings.display_errors = 1
resources.frontController.params.displayExceptions = 1

resources.db.params.profiler.enabled = true
resources.db.params.profiler.class = Zend_Db_Profiler_Firebug
```

with the above setting everything works fine. but I can not create any other folder in root directory. 
If I create new folder as named abc and access like domain.com/abc I can not access. it treats this as a controller action.

Please help me how can I resolve this. 
To resolve this I tried to place index.php in root directory from public folder. after that nothing works properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update .htacces with below code

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^js/(.*)$     public/js/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^images/(.*)$     public/images/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^css/(.*)$     public/css/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the principle of Zend, it treats to retrieve url (module), the controller and action.
You can try to set up [routing](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.controller.router.html#zend.controller.router.routes) for anayser url differently.
Otherwise, if it is to access doccuments accessible to everyone, you can put them in public.

I hope it will help